# log monitoring script which needs more functionality

Tags: bash, unix

I have written below log monitoring script to egrep multiple words and redirect the output to a text file and its working fine but I want to add some more below given functionality to it, which is very advance and im not very good in it, so please help if you can :)

1. I am egrepping all the error codes, so I want rather than egrepping all error codes, i should grep for "HTTP/1.1" 200" which is successful code and which ever line does not have this redirects output to output file.
2. ignore any line which has "/akamai/sureroute"
3. right now i am using cronjob to run this script every 5 min, so my script will send the same error again and again, so i want the script not to send the same error more than 3 times. (based on the time stamp).
4. for eg. if server goes down I do not want 1000's error messages, so if there are more than 100 error messages, script should send only 1 mail.

=============

```
find /home/bharat/ -type f -name "apache_logs.txt" |while read file
  do
    RESULT=$(egrep "[^0](400|401|403|404|405|406|407|408|409|410|411|412|413|414|415|416|417|418|422|425|426|428|429|431|451|500|501|502|503|504|505|511)" $file)
      if [[ ! -z $RESULT ]]
         then
            echo "Error(s) in $file on $HOSTNAME at "$(date)": $RESULT">> email_result.txt
     fi
  done
```

Comment: Don't invoke grep in a loop.  Instead do `find ... -exec grep -H pattern {} \;`

Comment: Rather than storing the result in a variable and echoing that that to the file (eg, accumulating all of the data in memory), just write the data to the file.

Comment: To black list lines instead of whitelisting them, use `grep -v`.  eg `grep -v 'HTTP/1.1" 200' ...`

Comment: thanks william pursell for input ,

Comment: Split your script into 2 phases. The first one accummulates all error messages (perhaps using offset where previous job left), and another for deciding what lines should be send to who.